# What is the most common way to front end tomcat with iis6

Tags: tomcat, iis-6, webserver

I want to run a few tomcat web apps behind IIS 6.  I was wondering what the most common way that this is accomplished.  I have done this with Apache using the AJP connector and using HTTP proxypass.  Is this done the same way with IIS 6? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IIS-Tomcat redirector

You can use the IIS-Tomcat Redirector, which is the commonly used plugin to achieve this.

Tomcat has a very neat documentation on How-To do this, which can be found at:

**http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html**

and

**http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html**

---

Alternative Quickfix

Alternatively, you can use the MSI setup provided at the link below, *"which allows you to skip steps 1 through 7 in the "Configuring the ISAPI Redirector" section of this page"*

**http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat_and_IIS_Howto**

Hope that helps